# Screen Orientation and ProgressDialog

Tags: android, screen, orientation, screen-orientation

My activity has 2 xml. In this activity i have to call a progressdialog who has a several minutes process. When the orientation changes, my progressdialog closes. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Upon orientation change, android destroys and recreates the activity/fragment. If you have a simple indeterminate progress dialog, you can just save the fact that the dialog was showing via onSaveInstanceState() and simply put the dialog back up on recreation.

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need a dialog that doesn't close upon the orientation changing, I recommend (and so does Google nowadays) using a `DialogFragment`.

You can find many helpful examples of code and implementation [here in the official android documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)